# How to change tick labels for plot chart from 19:00-7:00 hours in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot line charts for both nighttime and daytime to compare the differences in traffic volume in both time periods.

```
plt.subplot(2,1,1) #plot in grid chart to better compare differences
by_hour_business_night['traffic_volume'].plot.line()
plt.title('Business Nights Traffic Volume by Hours')
plt.ylabel('Traffic Volume')

plt.ylim(0,6500)
plt.show()
```

The chart for nighttime shows up alright, but the xtick labels are in [0,5,10,15,20,25], how can I change the labels to fit the hours? Something along the lines like: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,19,20,21,22,23]

I have tried

```
x=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,19,20,21,22,23]
plt.xticks(x)
```

But then I just got [0-6] on the left, and [19-23] on the right, both crammed on either side, leaving the middle of the xticks blank.

Or is there a better way to plot the chart? Since there will be a breaking point between 6 and 19 hours, is there a way to avoid this?

I am new to python and matplotlib, so forgive me if my wordings aren't precise enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xticks takes in two arguments: an array-like object of the placements and an array-like object of the labels. So you can do something like this:

```
plt.xticks(x, x)
```

This will set a label equal to the placement of the xtick. For more info you can [read the docs for xtick here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html)

Comment: Great, thanks, I finally got it to work, though I'm not quite sure why. I ended up using x = np.arange(0, 24, 2) for xtick location because using x = np.arange(0, 12,1) still got all the ticks crammed to the left.